# mysql - one more complex query or two simple

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to know which query is better. I want to select some specific records and all count of records in table(but filtered).

Which query is better?

```
SELECT name, surname,
        (select COUNT(messages.id) from messages WHERE `messages`.`archived` = '0' AND `type` IN (0, 1) ) as count
FROM messages JOIN
     users
      ON users.id = messages.user_id
WHERE messages.archived = 0 AND type = 0 OR type = 1
ORDER BY created_on DESC
LIMIT 3
```

or

```
SELECT name, surname
FROM messages JOIN
     users
     ON users.id = messages.user_id
WHERE messages.archived = 0 AND type = 0 OR type = 1
ORDER BY created_on DESC
LIMIT 3
```

with

```
SELECT count(id) as count
FROM messages
WHERE `messages`.`archived` = '0' AND `type` IN (0, 1)
```

If I have big db I will check this out, but for now I have got a few records.

With single query the count is added to every record.

Thanks and sorry for my english!

Comment: The two methods does not count the same thing: in the first query you count all the messages in the table and the in second one you count only the ones that match a condition.

Comment: Maybe you should describe in words what you want the query to achieve as these examples you have posted will not all do the same thing as @Xebax says so its difficult to know how to answer althought there will be those that will attempt a guess

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I would like to query count of messages WHERE `messages`.`archived` = '0' AND `type` IN (0, 1), so first more complex query is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

After writing this, I realized that the two queries are not the same.  So, you should use the version that corresponds the results you want to get.  (Do you want the count filtered or not?)

I'm not sure if MySQL will optimize the subquery in the `SELECT`.  However, you can just move it into the `FROM` clause, where it is only run once:

```
SELECT `name`, `surname`, m.cnt
FROM `messages` JOIN
     `users`
      ON `users`.`id` = `messages`.`user_id` CROSS JOIN
      (select COUNT(messages.id) as cnt from messages) m
WHERE `messages`.`archived` = '0' AND `type` = 0 OR `type` = 1
ORDER BY `created_on` DESC;
LIMIT 3
```

I suspect your `WHERE` clause is incorrect.  Do you really intend this?

```
WHERE `messages`.`archived` = '0' AND `type` IN (0, 1)
```

Comment: ... or at least `WHERE messages.archived = 0 AND (type = 0 OR type = 1)`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I would like to query count of messages WHERE `messages`.`archived` = '0' AND `type` IN (0, 1), so my first more complex query is wrong.

Comment: @Ridd . . . Then you can put those conditions in the subquery in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I added something like '..from messages where messages.type = sleep(1)) m...' and now I see that mysql count subquery every time so maybe I should stay with two simple query, not 1 complex? Thanks for your responses.